# How to open *.class files with decompiler by default in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, settings, decompiler

When opening a *.class file in Eclipse, the default `Class File Viewer` editor is used showing a not coder-friendly view of the class.

Having several decompilers installed on my Eclipse instance, I can "manually" use any them to open my *.class file so it shows in the `Class Decompiler Viewer` editor.

What I would like though is to change the default editor from `Class File Viewer` to `Class Decompiler Viewer` so when I open a *.class file (e.g. by double-clicking it in the `Package Explorer` view or via the `Open Type...` dialog) it opens directly in the right view.

At the moment *.class files are consistently opening in the `Class File Viewer` editor regardless of my settings. I have to go back to the `Package Explorer` view, right-click the *.class file and select the desired decompiler explicitely in the `Open Class With` option to get it open in the `Class Decompiler Viewer` editor.

I have set the `Class Decompiler Viewer` editor as the default one for *.class files, applied, restarted Eclipse even, but still all the *.class files I open are coming through the `Class File Viewer` by default.
[image]

The decompiler preference also has an option to set himslef as the default editor of *.class files, but without success on my side:
[image]

Any idea of a solution to force the default *.class file editor to something else than the `Class File Viewer` one? Am I missing something obvious in my settings?

Comment: better to download new version eclipse - oxygen - Class Decompiler Viewer automatically enabled.

Comment: I have the latest Eclipse release, with the Enhanced Class Decompiler, and apparently configured about the same as you, and it works fine for me. Your first sentence refers to "a not coder-friendly view of the class". What does that mean?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr "a not coder-friendly view of the class" means the `Class File Viewer` editor does not show the class content as Java code per say, but plain text with unpleasant formatting. Decompiling properly or attaching the ad-hoc source gives a much better experience

Comment: Good point @LovaChittumuri I forgot to precise I use Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) which is I believe one of the latest versions of Oxygen.

Comment: 2020-12 is the latest released version of Eclipse (as of today), not Oxygen. Oxygen is itself a particular release of Eclipse, which is four years old.

Comment: My experience is the same as that of David Karr. It has happened to me in the past that occasionally Eclipse somehow damages its configuration. Possibly deleting Eclipse completely, then reinstalling it, then configuring it with the desired settings, will solve the problem. Workspaces and such should stay intact, you only need to reinstall the plugins. There are buttons in the lower left corner of the preferences dialog to export and import the configuration. I don't know how well this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In File Associations below "*.class", you will find another "*.class without source". Set your decompiler as default in that. Class files should open in the decompiler now.

Comment: That was it, thanks @reactiveself! So simple yet so tricky to get in the first place...

Comment: I have opposite issue, I have attached the source and they keep being opened with decompiler, any idea? Thanks